# Get page name from URI, substring between two characters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, substring

I want to get the page name from a URI for instance if I have

```
"/Pages/Alarm/AlarmClockPage.xaml"
```

I want to get `AlarmClockPage`

I tried

```
//usage GetSubstring("/", ".", "/Pages/Alarm/AlarmClockPage.xaml")
 public static string GetSubstring(string a, string b, string c)
 {  
     string str = c.Substring((c.IndexOf(a) + a.Length),
          (c.IndexOf(b) - c.IndexOf(a) - a.Length));

     return str;
 }
```

But because the string being search may contain one or more forward slashes, I don't think this method work in such case.

So how do I consider the multiple forward slashes that may present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use method which is already in the framework?

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"/Pages/Alarm/AlarmClockPage.xaml");
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I must include `@` in the path parameter?

Comment: @PutraKg - only if you have characters to escape in the string. It's not necessary in the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use string functions, you may try:

```
var startIdx = pathString.LastIndexOf(@"/");
var endIdx = pathString.LastIndexOf(".");
if(endIdx!=-1)
{
    fileName = pathString.Substring(startIdx,endIdx);
}
else
{
    fileName = pathString.Substring(startIdx);
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the built in function? It handles forward or back-slash.

Comment: Of course I'll use them, I just suggested this because the op was trying to do it in that way @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 0):

It gives file name from a given file path. try this

```
string pageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"/Pages/Alarm/AlarmClockPage.xaml");
```